# Java web framework to design UI easily

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java web. Can anyone recommend some useful and efficient web framework to create UI and develop the code using Java? I am a core Java developer.

UPDATED
Thank you for your guidance guys i am planning to go with GWT ..and once again Thankyou...

Answer (score 3):

Java Web Frameworks might not help you in designing UI, in real sense. You might need to look at JavaScript frameworks for that, i.e. YUI, jQuery, Scriptaculous, extJS etc..

However, Wicket and Stripes, are good among Java Web Frameworks for rapid development. Found a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742223/what-is-the-most-commonly-used-java-web-framework/742993#742993) about mostly used Java Web Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) ( http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ ). This will allow you to create most of your UI using Java only.

Comment: ya but it is not easy to deploy in other servers like tomcat or jetty

Comment: http://designandcode.blogspot.com/2006/09/deploy-google-web-toolkitgwt.html might help you with deployment on Tomcat.

Comment: i tried it as i am new to J2EE as i mentioned already it founds hard to deploy ....

Answer (score 1):

[Vaadin (www.vaadin.com)](http://vaadin.com/learn) may be one to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Flex (licensed) and integrate it with Java.  It provides rich UI toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend GWT. Not only for client side possibilities, but also for integration in IDE - Eclipse plugin, Netbeans plugin (GWT4NB), client-server capabilities with RPC helps to use a lot of already done work (java libraries) on server side. 
Integration with Tomcat or another servlet container is of course also the main funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be problems with deploying GWT in Tomcat?